# How to sum up third elements of string in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following output:

```
["1154,1,8.00", "1162,1,8.00", "1161,1,8.00"]
```

I would like to sum the third element of each item: `8.00 + 8.00 + 8.00`

I've tried with `.last, .map` with no luck.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: By "output" you probably mean "input". The output would be "24.00"

Comment: "no luck" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```rb
["1154,1,8.00", "1162,1,8.00", "1161,1,8.00"].sum { |x| x.split(',').last.to_f }

# output
# => 24.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = ["1154,1,8.00", "1162,1,8.00", "1161,1,8.00"]
```

```
rgx = /(?<=,)(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2}\z/
```

```
arr.sum { |s| s[rgx].to_f }
  #=> 24.0
```

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
/
(?<=,)    # positive lookbehind asserts previous character is ','
(?:       # begin non-capture group
  0       # match '0'
  |       # or
  [1-9]   # match a digit other than '0'
  \d*     # match zero or more digits
)         # end non-capture group
\.        # match '.'
\d{2}     # match two digits
\z        # match end of string
/
```